# Why is the command 'sudo pip uninstall' not working?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, sudo

When I type the following command in Ubuntu, it is showing all list of python packages:

```
$  sudo pip list
adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.2)
apt-xapian-index (0.44)
apturl (0.5.1ubuntu3)
argparse (1.2.1)
BeautifulSoup (3.2.0)
Brlapi (0.5.6)
bzr (2.5.1)
chardet (2.0.1)
command-not-found (0.2.44)
dirspec (3.0.0)
distribute (0.7.3)
dnspython (1.9.4)
docutils (0.8.1)
duplicity (0.6.18)
gdata (2.0.14)
GnuPGInterface (0.3.2)
httplib2 (0.7.2)
jockey (0.9.7)
louis (2.3.0)
mercurial (2.0.2)
nvidia-common (0.0.0)
onboard (0.97.1)
oneconf (0.2.8.1)
PAM (0.4.2)
paramiko (1.7.7.1)
pexpect (2.3)
pip (1.4.1)
piston-mini-client (0.7.2)
Pmw (1.3.2)
psutil (0.4.1)
psycopg2 (2.4.5)
PyChart (1.39)
pycrypto (2.4.1)
pycups (1.9.61)
pycurl (7.19.0)
pydot (1.0.2)
pyinotify (0.9.2)
pyOpenSSL (0.12)
pyparsing (1.5.2)
pyserial (2.5)
pysmbc (1.0.13)
python-apt (0.8.3ubuntu7.2)
python-ldap (2.3.13)
python-openid (2.2.5)
python-virtkey (0.60.0)
pyxdg (0.19)
PyYAML (3.10)
reportlab (2.5)
sessioninstaller (0.0.0)
setuptools (0.8b2)
simplejson (2.3.2)
system-service (0.1.6)
Twisted-Core (11.1.0)
Twisted-Names (11.1.0)
Twisted-Web (11.1.0)
ubuntuone-couch (0.3.0)
ubuntuone-installer (3.0.2)
ubuntuone-storage-protocol (3.0.2)
ufw (0.31.1-1)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
unittest2 (0.5.1)
unity-lens-video (0.3.5)
unity-scope-video-remote (0.3.5)
usb-creator (0.2.23)
uTidylib (0.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
xdiagnose (2.5.3)
xkit (0.0.0)
xlwt (0.7.2)
ZSI (2.1-a1)
```

When I import a particular package, it is working perfect:

```
$ sudo python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
>>>
```

But when I try to uninstall particular package, it throws an error like this:

```
$  sudo pip uninstall argparse
Can't uninstall 'argparse'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Why I am facing above problem?

Comment: was the said package (argparse in your example) installed using pip or using your distribution's package manager? Whatever mean was used to install it, you should use the same to uninstall it.

Comment: Have you `sudo` installed that package?

Comment: @MatToufoutu thanks for reply. at package installation time i have not used pip. But I need to uninstall those packages now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't used pip to install `argparse` (unlikely, as it is python core library), you don't use pip to uninstall it.

Comment: Do you have any good reason to uninstall it?  It's core lib so it should be there in any standard python installation.  Describe the problem you are actually facing

Comment: you can find `BeautifulSoup (3.2.0)` from my list, this is not core lib i think. In this case I gave example `argparse` to uninstall, ok this is not good as you said. But I need to uninstall `BeautifulSoup`. How to handle this ?

Comment: maybe you installed it with `apt-get`. there's a package called `python-beautifulsoup`

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge python-beautifulsoup`

Comment: Thanks I lastly realized you are correct. I have successfully uninstalled the `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: @wim: I have `argparse 1.2.1`, `argparse 1.2.2` is available, but pip cannot install it because it cannot uninstall `argparse 1.2.1`. I have Ubuntu 14.10 and no idea when (if) I installed argparse.

Comment: @wim: Eventually it is part of `libpython2.7-stdlib`? However, I hesitate to uninstall that ... I have no idea what consequences this might have.

Comment: try install with the wheel -> `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/a/argparse/argparse-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 0):

For not-too-old python versions (python 2.7+), `argparse` is part of the python distribution, and therefore you can't uninstall it easily (and it's not a good idea to do this anyway).

As per the comments, there is a possibility to do this using `easy_install -m` and then deleting the `.egg` file.

Also afaik, you can't generally uninstall packages with `pip` that you haven't *installed* with `pip`. Use whatever you installed a package with, to uninstall it. Your package manager (`apt-get`) is one option here.

Comment: yes, I know (and wrote it in the first part of the answer). the second part is a more general part of the answer. no need to -1 here.

Comment: -1 because you _can_ uninstall argparse.  It's just not a good idea, that's all.

Comment: and how would you uninstall argparse? now I'm curious. :-) `pip` and `apt-get` are out, what's left (except deleting files manually)?

Comment: Although argparse is core library, it is still just an external module installed in site-packages (I think you should be able to remove it with `easy_install -m` and then delete the .egg).  I downvoted you because your answer has incorrect information ("afaik"), don't take it personally.

Comment: On my ubuntu install, argparse lives in `/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py`, not in site-packages.

Comment: OK, so it's not always in site-packages then (I guess you have `argparse.egg-info` file in the same directory?).  Nonetheless, it is still a python module, not C code.  If you simply delete or rename that argparse.py file, you are effectively uninstalling the module and you will find you can no longer `import argparse` in python.

Comment: Note that argparse is new in 2.7, prior to that python used optparse and you would install/uninstall the argparse module as any other external package.

Comment: "Note that argparse is new in 2.7" yeah, that info is also in my answer since the beginning. anyway, I'll edit your uninstall procedure to the answer, and let this be now.